# Timer called during Vapor request never fires

Tags: swift, timer, vapor

Are there any issues around creating a timer in the context of a request in Vapor? I need to trigger an action that takes place several minutes after a user initiates a process. So far, when I call the routine that does this, I get confirmation that the code that sets up the timer has run. But neither the timer, nor a call to the main DispatchQueue ever fires.
The method that calls the setup redirects the user immediately afterwards to another endpoint, and I'm wondering if this is why.

```swift
func startTournament(req: Request) -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
    let uId : UUID = req.auth.get(User.self)!.id!
    var tourn : Tournament?
    return User.query(on: req.db)
        .with(\.$tournament)  { $0.with(\.$invitations)}
        .filter(\.$id == uId)
        .first().flatMap { u  in
            tourn = u!.tournament!
            Tournament.addTournamentTimer(tourn!)
```

is the code where the setup is called.

This is the method called, and the print statement executes:

```swift
static func addTournamentTimer(_ tourn : Tournament) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        print("Timer fired!")
    }
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { timer in
        print("Timer fired!")
    }
    print("adding timer for tournament \(tourn.name)")
}
```

I don't want to use the DispatchQueue approach, but I tried including it to see if it worked. It doesn't seem to. I'm fairly new to using timers, but I have a fair number of functions that work on timers in a client app, so I'm quite able to figure them out elsewhere. Again, I'm assuming this is something not clear to me about asynchronous
requests, and or the timer getting dumped when the redirect happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to set a timer on server-side is to use NIO instead of GCD.

Take an `eventLoop` and check its `schedule...` methods to choose the right one for your situation.

Here is an example of your method with NIO:

```swift
static func addTournamentTimer(_ tourn : Tournament, on req: Request) {
    req.eventLoop.scheduleTask(deadline: NIODeadline.now() + .seconds(5)) {
        print("Timer fired!")
    }
    print("adding timer for tournament \(tourn.name)")
}
```

Comment: using this method, can I assign it to a variable that I can a.) access later, and b.) either replace or modify the deadline date? in my usage, an initial deadline has to be extended if certain events happen. A timer provides a convenient way to do this…

Comment: Trying the approach out, and it works very well. My new question is an extension of the above comment: When I get a Scheduled object from creating a scheduledTask, what am I getting? I need to be able to store these in a Dictionary with the UUID of the object they are associated with. What would the type of the object stored in the Dictionary be?

Comment: The type of stored object is `Scheduled<T>` and it has only `cancel()` method. So it is not that rich as you expect. You also could take a look at Vapor docs about queues https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/queues/

Comment: …as I'm learning. Thanks for your input; I've marked the answer correct because it fits the limits of the original question. What I'm going to do, I think, is have the scheduled event run, but check at execution time if the deadline to perform the action has been extended, via a dictionary that stores any subsequent changes. That way, I can simply schedule a new event, and have that execute at the delayed time.